# How (if possible) can I configure Eclipse with Intellij IDEA keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I have to work with Eclipse for a while and coming from Intellij I would love to keep using the shortcuts that I know and love. Is there a simple way to configure Eclipse with Intellij's keybord shortcuts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that Eclipse has native support for the Intellij key scheme, but you have a plugin here: http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/intellij_idea_key_scheme_for that might do the trick.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I found a more up to date version of the plugin here, but I've yet to get it working with the latest version of STS. http://code.google.com/p/ideakeyscheme/

Comment: I wasn't aware of that one, nice find :D I hope you can get it to work.

Comment: the following github repo includes the jar file (save it to the `eclipse/dropins` folder): https://github.com/ChillingVan/ideakeyscheme